# Enable HiDPI on 23" iMac?

Tags: macos, imac, resolution

I have a 23" iMac running Lion (10.7.3). I've checked that the "Enable HiDPI display modes" checkbox is enabled in "Quartz Debug" (it was checked the first time I opened it), but there are no HiDPI resolution options in my display settings.

Has anyone had success with using HiDPI display modes on a 23" iMac?

Comment: I have the same problem and even after logging out and back in *and* restarting, HiDPI mode does not work at all. When I log back in, the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the instructions on the screen, you have to log out and back in when enabling or disabling HiDPI mode for the changes to take effect:

[image]

Comment: Do you know what they mean by "virtual display modes" here?

Comment: @Ken Virtual displays refers to hooking up a retina iOS device as a second monitor, and enabling the HiDPI mode on that "display".

Comment: This doesn't work for me...still...

Answer (score 2):

If the checkbox is already enabled, but it doesn't work, disable it, logout when prompted to, login again, re-enable it and at the next login you should find the HiDPI settings in the Displays settings.

Comment: Do you know what causes this problem? I had two accounts logged in and had to sign out both accounts before I could successfully change the setting.