# How do you enable HiDpi mode for unsupported monitors like the Dell P2815Q in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, resolution, display

Has anyone figured out how to enable HiDPI mode for the Dell p2815Q on Mac OS X 10.9? I have tried Quartz Debug, default write commands at the terminal and SwitchResX, to no avail.

Comment: ColorSync? You mean System Preferences? That only shows two options: native resolution or 1080p. Holding alt yields many more, but no HiDpi options, not even the ones I created with SwitchResX.

Comment: The ColorSync utility.app located in the utility folder! what profile does it use/show in the ColorSync utility now? Also, maybe you can explain what is not working now with Quartz debug mode? Further, what Terminal commands have you tried, so we do not waist our the recommending the same.

Comment: Okay, where in ColorSync? I see all the profiles listed in the Profiles tab. I've never used this utility, so I'll need more details. With Quartz Debug, I checked to see if the "enable HiDpi" button was selected. It was. I deselected, and reselected it, and rebooted. Nothing. The command I ran was: sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool YES;

Comment: If your monitor is listed in ColorSyc what profile has it assigned to it?

Comment: Listed in which tab?

Comment: If you mean the Displays sub tree in the Devices tab, the factory profile is "Dell P2815Q" and the Current Profile is one that I created in the color tab in displays in system preferences (same name plus "calibrated").

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here:

Basically, per [Apple’s website](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Testing/Testing.html) you:

1. Open Mac App Store

   2. Download XCode (free)
   3. Follow their instructions to download Graphics Tools for Xcode package
   4. Run Quartz Debug, following the instructions [here on StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48433/enable-hidpi-on-23-imac?rq=1), making sure to note that you will have to make each settings change and log out of your account each time, and if your computer has multiple accounts you may have to do the same on each one! (What a pain!)
   5. Somehow it should automagically work out that the next time you log in, you can choose HiDPI settings in your Displays control panel.